# What optimizations does Python do without the -O flags?

Tags: python, optimization, bytecode

I had always assumed that the Python interpreter did no optimizations without a `-O` flag, but the following is a bit strange:

```
>>> def foo():
...     print '%s' % 'Hello world'
...
>>> from dis import dis 
>>> dis(foo)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               3 ('Hello world')
              3 PRINT_ITEM          
              4 PRINT_NEWLINE       
              5 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              8 RETURN_VALUE
```

It appears as though the interpreter is doing some folding on the modulo of two string constants.  If I add a variable in though, it gives an unoptimized result:

```
>>> def foo():
...     s = 'Hello world!'
...     print '%s' % s
... 
>>> dis(foo)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('Hello world!')
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (s)

  3           6 LOAD_CONST               2 ('%s')
              9 LOAD_FAST                0 (s)
             12 BINARY_MODULO       
             13 PRINT_ITEM          
             14 PRINT_NEWLINE       
             15 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             18 RETURN_VALUE
```

What optimizations does Python do without the -O flag?  And is there any way to disable them?  I'd like to see how unoptimized Python bytecode will look.  I don't plan on doing this in any production type environment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yep, it does do constant folding, here's a simpler example:

```
>>> def f(): return 23+100
... 
>>> dis.dis(f)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               3 (123)
              3 RETURN_VALUE        
>>>
```

No way to block this (except by changing sources) AFAIK.

**Edit**: for all the optimization flow, see [peephole.c](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Python/peephole.c?annotate=73683) -- this is also probably the handiest place to "change sources", e.g. change line 320 from

```
if (codelen > 32700)
```

to

```
if (codelen > 0)
```

to make sure all optimizations are unconditionally disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to walk around constant folding:

```
>>> dis.dis(lambda: (3,)[0]+(4,)[0])
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               5 (3)
              3 LOAD_CONST               7 (4)
              6 BINARY_ADD          
              7 RETURN_VALUE
```

Watch out for the extra constants, though:

```
>>> (lambda: (3,)[0]+(4,0)[0]).func_code.co_consts
(None, 3, 0, 4, (3,), 3, (4, 0), 4)
```